# How to prevent scrappers looping the URL?

Tags: asp.net-core, web-scraping

I have an asp.net core website with a URL pattern like this.

```
https://test.com/specs/24/panasonic-24-inch
```

How do I prevent someone from running a for-loop and scraping my data?

What is the mechanism available in asp.net core to prevent this.

My thought is to store the IP addresses when someone visit the page and if the same IP request the page less than 5 seconds send an empty HTML. But then what happen if google bot scrawl my site? I don't want to block it.

I get that this question doesn't have an exact answer. So please share your thoughts regarding this. Not every question has an exact answer. We know that.

Comment: You're asking how to avoid id enumeration. The best way to prevent it is to change your ids from sequential numbers to hashes/uuids, so they can't be enumerated. Depending on what type of data it is, you could also require logging in to access only IDs you have access to. If you can't do either, you're out of luck, because you can't prevent someone from scraping every ID if it's a public URL.

Comment: Make condition to only allow google scrawler?